# Fetch image as a url from mysql database in laravel Api

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5

I want to fetch the image from database as a URL like http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploads/category/image.png
but the result I am getting is the name of the file not the URL.

This is the model class:

```
    class CategoryModel extends Model
       {
       protected $table="tb_category";
       public $timestamps = false;

       protected $fillable = [
       'id',
       'name',
       'image'
       ];
       }
```

This is my controller class:

```
    class CategoryController extends Controller
    {
    //
    public function viewPage(){
        return view('category');
    }

    public function saveCategory(Request $request){
        $category = new CategoryModel();
        $category->name=$request->input('name');

        if($request->hasfile('image')){
            $file=$request->file('image');
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename=time().'.'.$extension;
            //$headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream');
            $file->move('uploads/category/',$filename);
            $category->image =$filename;
            $category->_image =$filename;



         }
         else{
            return $request;
            $category->image='';
            $category->_image=null;
         }

            $category->save();
            return view('category')->with('category',$category);

        }


        public function getCategories(){
        $res = CategoryModel::get(
            ['id','name','image'
         ]
         );   
         return response()->json($res,200);
         }
         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `saveCategory` method, you're storing `$filename` in 'image' column.
Change it to store path.

```
public function saveCategory(Request $request){
$category = new CategoryModel();
$category->name=$request->input('name');

if($request->hasfile('image')){
    $file=$request->file('image');
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $filename=time().'.'.$extension;
    $file->move('uploads/category/',$filename);
    $category->image ='http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploads/category/'.$filename; //This is where you need to save absolute path of the image.
 }
 else{
    return $request;

 }

    $category->save();
    return view('category')->with('category',$category);

}
```

One more problem here is that you've written code after `return $request;` in `else` statement. Any code written after `return` is unreachable for the interpreter and will not be executed.

Comment: Thank You @Qumber Rizvi
it solve the problem but the url after calling a get api and in that there are 2 '/' in the url and when we hit the image url it shows no but after removing the extra '/' I'm getting the output.
Can you please help me out with this too.

Comment: @MOHSINALI Could you show me an example URI please? Where are the double slashes being placed?

Comment: @MOHSINALI See if using `urlencode()` solves your problem. In the above method add urlencode around the path. `$category->image =urlencode('http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploads/category/'.$filename);`

Comment: http:\/\/127.0.0.1:8000\/uploads\/category3\/1583370615.png

this how url is return in api

Comment: urlencode return this
http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8000%2Fuploads%2Fcategory3%2F1583397539.jpg
which is again not the required output